# Google Drive viewer "document to images" conversion: is there an API for that?

Tags: google-drive-api

We are developing a document viewer to show documents to our users in the browser (webapp). We would like to use the excellent "document to images" feature of the Google Drive Viewer to convert our documents (PDF, Word, Excel, ...) to images.

Is it possible in any way? (API, libraries that we could run on our servers, other ideas?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This one might be worth a look: http://saaspose.com/

From their front page:

> Saaspose is a cloud-based document generation, conversion and automation platform for developers.

From the description of their Words API:

> Saaspose.Words, a cloud-based document creation, manipulation and conversion API, helps you process documents with its many flexible features. Saaspose.Words’ platform independent document manipulation API is a true REST API that can be used with any language: .NET, Java, PHP, Ruby, Rails, Python, jQuery and many more. The API integrates with other cloud services to give you the flexibility you need when processing documents.

Comment: It looks interesting but we're looking for something with no subscription model.

Answer (score 0):

A search for Google Drive Viewer returned a third party Chrome extension.

The Google Drive API does allow for file conversions, but the closest to your needs would seem to be conversion to a pdf file
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app

You can try a file export here
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/export

In the "Try this API" box, enter the fileID of one of your files, and put 
application/pdf
in the MIME type box and click on the execute button.